# Canada Visitor Visa Proof Of Funds

Tags: visas, canada, money, tourist-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

Im trying to apply for a Canada Tourist Visa to go and visit a friend **for a period of 12-days.**

Amongst a dozen other things I must show proof of funds. Proof of funds, according to Canada Imigration Center / Website states the following, as can be seen on image

[image]

**My Question(s)**

I have the following questions

1. If I go to the bank and make an exchange for lets say $2000 for a 12 day visit. **Can I use that currency exchange slip I will be getting as proof of sufficient finance for my 12-day visit?** (Keep in mind my accommodation is free my friend provides a letter as proof of residence and citizenship)
2. Is the exchange slip which I will be receiving after converting the money called a *convertible bank draft* as highlighted on image?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You asked us not to judge and that's fair enough, but " get paid mostly cash in hand" to an ECO that means possible drug dealer, trafficker, weapon sales, prostitution, and so on. And they DO judge.

Comment: @GayotFow they are *paid* to judge :)

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee the problem is, theres no *proof* of that :/ No company books, no tax returns stating your income etc etc Nothing to say the money is *legitimate* - and thats what they are interested in.

Comment: @Moo ok fair enough but my wife is the primary bread winner she is making a declaration that she will be my financial sponsor and provide all necessary docs, whilst my friend issues a document saying she will be providing me with accommodation. so....even though I have nothing to show (except buying foreign currency myself) If you were an immigration officer would those docs satisfy you

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee do you not share a bank account with your wife that you can use to show funds available and a decent history of activity (her salary being paid, expenses being spent etc)?  I am not an immigration officer, I cannot make that judgement.

Comment: @MOO yes her bank statements, payslips, tax returns etc are perfect. Unfortunately it is not a dual account, however we could go to bank today and make it a dual account....but not sure if that may look suspicious.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee oops, you have just disclosed that you have no means of on-going income during your time in Canada. They will pick on stuff like that. That's in addition to fitting the profile of a drug dealer, etc etc. But note that we're not decision-makers and for sure we're not the Tribunal.

Comment: @GayotFow but I do I have $2000-$3000 CND dollars (can get more), free accommodation for 12-nights and a financial sponsor so I dont get what you are saying...I realize its a weird situation. I can add I am a current student which I am, perhaps that would help

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee the issue is that your $2000-$3000 is currently very very suspicious and you have no way of dispelling that suspicion.  Financial sponsors only help a little, since Canadian immigration has no actual way to force the sponsor to pay for anything, so your application falls back on its own merits.

Comment: Weird situations are precisely what gets applications looked at in much more detail and scrutiny.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the exchange slip which I will be receiving after converting the money called a convertible bank draft as highlighted on image?

No.  Your currency exchange slip is a receipt, its proof that a transaction took place but nothing more.

A convertible bank draft is a cheque issued by the bank (commonly called a `cashiers cheque`, `teller's check` or `bankers draft`) which can be drawn on in any Canadian bank in Canadian currency - that is what it means by convertible, it needs to be able to be converted from the currency it was issued to the currency to be drawn, and not all bankers drafts can do that.

> get paid mostly cash in hand to avoid taxes among others (dont judge)

Its worth noting that this is *exactly* why immigration officials ask for provenance of funds - they want to avoid money with this sort of background.

I don't know about Canada, but when applying for a UK visa, the UK immigration officer inspecting your case has to be satisfied of the legality of funds under the same UK laws as everyone else in the UK has to abide by, which means any earnings should have had tax paid on them to the extent required by domestic law in the applicants country etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, so what can I do to proof I have enough cash in hand when entering the country? I dont quite get it...? When showing bank statments it will be in THB (Thai Baht) is that okay / willl it be a problem? Also according to your answer will the best way be to go to my bank and ask if they can issue me a `cashiers cheque` for Canada? What if they can not do this? Is what you referring to the same as a `travelers cheque`?

Comment: thanks again for your update and answer. My primary question basicallly changed to is a `cashiers cheque` the same as a `travelers cheque`?

Comment: No, a `cashiers cheque` is not the same as a `travellers cheque` but they are very very very similar - both are guaranteed funds, they are just different approaches to the same thing, with the main difference being that you can sign over a travellers cheque to anyone, but you may not be able to do that with a bankers draft.  Its probable that Canadian immigration would accept travellers cheques in lieu of a bankers draft, but they would probably be treated as cash.

Comment: Bank statements in a foreign currency is not an issue, the immigration officer inspecting your application will do a conversion using a common system.  The main thing bank statements prove is the *provenance of funds*.

Comment: Sorry for bombarding you with questions. You have been very helpful. Im submitting my visa application today so trying to avoid any hick ups. In YOUR opinion considering requirements from above image would you say a `travelers cheque` would help my application?  (In your opinion)

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee your main issue is going to prove the cash (in whatever form, be it draft or travellers cheques) isn't illegal...  in my *opinion* the only thing that I can see being an issue with travellers cheques is that they are anonymous currency, there is no paper trail involved in their use.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee for the visa application they're unlikely to care about how you plan to bring your funds into Canada.  They just want to know that you have enough money, and that the money is legitimate.  When you arrive at the border, they may ask to see how much money you've brought, and in what form.  It doesn't matter if it's in a foreign currency, because those can of course be converted to local currency.  It could also be enough just to show them a credit card.  But in practice, it's rare to be asked to show such things.  You seems to be concerning yourself with the wrong details.